# Sqlalchemy query to count the times that a value exist in a column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Having the table `A` a the column named `letter` and an example of it below

```
1.a
2.b
3.c
4.a
5.a
2.b
```

Is there any way to use sqlalchemy to count how many times the values exist in the column to get something like the above?

```
1.a,3
2.b,2
3.c,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of `count()` and `group_by()` should do the trick:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(A.letter, func.count(A.letter)).group_by(A.letter).all()
```

Comment: How can I do the same query with Model class? When I execute `A.query(A.letter, func.count(A.letter)).group_by(A.letter).all()` I get `TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable`?